# How get state Enable/Disabled of Button History.forward() / History.back()

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

With Javascript is usually use window.history.back() to go to previous page and window.history.forward() to go to next page.

But sometimes the Button ( or back or forward ) are disabled
because don't exist "any" history to change the URL.

How I can get these buttons states ?